# Accumulating atoms into a list without recursion Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a Prolog program that takes user input and makes decisions based on the semantics of the input (basically a chatbot).

I had originally thought (being not a logic programmer) that I would check against multiple sets of words (i.e., interrogatives, family words, words with good/bad emotional content), then accumulate atoms that describe the types of words used into a list, and then check against that list to decide what to say.

Obviously, this doesn't work, so now I'm pretty much lost.  Is there a way to even do something like this in Prolog, or am I thinking about it all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my answer ended up going away from the idea of lists, and using predicates instead:

```
maleWords(  [he, him, his]).
femaleWords([she, her, hers]).
familyWords([mother, mom, father, dad, sister, brother]).
goodEmotes( [happy, ecstatic, great, good, yay, love, like, better, best]).
badEmotes(  [sad, bad, horrible, depressed, sucks, death, die, died, dead]).

chat:-writeln('What\'s on your mind?'), bot.
bot:-readln(A),
 maplist(downcase_atom, A, X),
 X \= [quit] ->
    maplist(checkAtom,X,Temp),
    sort(Temp,List),
    wrt(List),
    bot;
 writeln('Fine. Ruin your life then.').

checkAtom(A,X):-
 maleWords(Y),   member(A,Y)-> X = maleW;
 femaleWords(Y), member(A,Y)-> X = femaleW;
 familyWords(Y), member(A,Y)-> X = family;
 goodEmotes(Y),  member(A,Y)-> X = goodEm;
 badEmotes(Y),   member(A,Y)-> X = badEm;
 X = nothing.

wrt(List):-
 sublist([badEm,family,femaleW],List) -> writeln('Do you feel like she\'s causing your problems?');
 sublist([badEm,family,maleW],List) -> writeln('Do you feel like he\'s causing your problems?');
 sublist([family,femaleW,goodEm],List) -> writeln('Do you feel like she\'s helping you?');
 sublist([family,goodEm,maleW],List) -> writeln('Do you feel like he\'s helping you?');
 writeln('Hmm.*writes on clipboard*').

%%%%%%% Got this predicate from another SO question... %%%%%%%%%%
sublist( [], _ ).
sublist( [X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist( XS, XSS ).
sublist( [X|XS], [_|XSS] ) :- sublist( [X|XS], XSS ).
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [`setof/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setof/3)?

It lets you collect the set of your results in a list:

```prolog
setof( Category, is_a(Word, Category), L),
say_something(Word, L), 
....
```

Comment: This looks like it would give me all of the categories that one word is in.  For my program, categories<->words is a one-to-one relationship.  I would like to get all of the categories that are represented by all of the words.  Is there a way to use `maplist` or something similar for that?

Comment: So I just realized, since I've got a set number of categories, I could just do `List :- [A,B,C,D...], intersects(UserInput,goodEmotes) -> A is goodEmote,` and so on, then check patterns on that list.  Is it bad form to answer your own question, or should I post that as an answer?

Comment: @KristenHammack it is perfectly OK to post your own answer to your question, and even accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use findall

Say that you have:

a( 'how are you', 'good' ).
a( 'how are you', 'not bad' ).

findall( Answer, a( 'how are you', Answer ), Answers )

In this, answers will have a list of items (in this case, 'good' and 'not bad')

Answer (score 0):

ELIZA, that's approaching 50 (!) birthdays, it's the most famous chatbot I know. You can google for 'ELIZA prolog source' and take the first answer, then adapt the database to your needs.